# How to initialize jQuery library in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, next.js

I know jQuery is aganst React principles, as it does direct DOM manipulations. But I need to use Revolution Slider library, and I found this the only way to do.

I would implement this tutorial:

http://zulijani.com/slider-revolution/sources/01.Sample-Boxed.html

but when I put the initializer into `_document.tsx`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                       jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution(
                        {
                            delay:9000,
                            startwidth:1170,
                            startheight:500,
                            hideThumbs:10
                        });
                });
            </script>
```

I got an error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: jQuery(...).revolution is not a function

Call Stack
HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
/ (3:40)
fire
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js (3074:30)
```

What can I do?

Full `_document.tsx`:

```
import Document, {
    Html,
    Head,
    Main,
    NextScript,
    DocumentContext,
} from 'next/document'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        return { ...initialProps }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    {/* get jQuery from the Google APIs */}
                    <script
                        type="text/javascript"
                        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"
                        crossOrigin="anonymous"
                    />

                    {/* CSS STYLE */}
                    <link
                        rel="stylesheet"
                        type="text/css"
                        href="css/style.css"
                        media="screen"
                    />

                    {/* SLIDER REVOLUTION 4.x SCRIPTS */}
                    <script
                        type="text/javascript"
                        src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"
                    />
                    <script
                        type="text/javascript"
                        src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"
                    />

                    {/* SLIDER REVOLUTION 4.x CSS SETTINGS */}
                    <link
                        rel="stylesheet"
                        type="text/css"
                        href="rs-plugin/css/settings.css"
                        media="screen"
                    />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                    {/* Initialize Slider Revolution in the body footer */}
                    <script
                        type="text/javascript"
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                            __html: `
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                  jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution({
                    delay: 9000,
                    startwidth: 1170,
                    startheight: 500,
                    hideThumbs: 10
                  });
                });
              `,
                        }}
                    />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use another library? After you overcome this jQuery problem, I think there are some terrible issues blocking you, eg. SSR error, turbo pack error, etc.

Comment: I purchased this template: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/zircona-it-solutions-technology-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/26902789 and it uses Revolution Slider. I like these animations. As I see other template uses RS also. What would you do in my place?

Comment: I found a similar one, but it is so much static: https://preview.themeforest.net/item/jano-creative-multipurpose-nextjs-template/full_screen_preview/44833644?_ga=2.215866579.517874256.1687272212-2063496053.1686430017

Comment: Actually a very interesting question, I hope you will solve it. If not try to add a bounty after a few days.